# @RequestHeader mapped value contains header twice

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

We are facing a super strange problem: in our endpoint:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/send_event_to_payment_process")
@Async
public void sendEvent(@Valid @RequestBody final SendEventRequestDto dto, @RequestHeader(value = TENANT) String foo) {
```

the mapped @RequestHeader variable foo contains the vaue twice joined with a ',' ("test,test"). If we read the header programmatically using the request context:

```
public void sendEvent(@Valid @RequestBody final SendEventRequestDto dto, @Context final HttpServletRequest request) {
final String tenant = request.getHeader(TENANT);
```

we receive the proper value (only once: "test").

Any clues what the problem might be?!

Thank you!

Comment: sounds like a type conversion is taking place from String[]. Try changing the type of the foo parameter to String[] to see whether you are getting 2 seperate values

Comment: Your answer also went to the right direction. I just did not understood the internals of Springs handing of the request headers. Thank you also for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing different things.

The `HttpServletRequest.getHeader` method always returns a single value, even if there are multiple values for the header. It will return the first (see the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader(java.lang.String)) of the method).

Spring uses the [`HttpServletRequest::getHeaders`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeaders(java.lang.String)) method to get all the values. Which retrieves all header values and, depending on the value, return the `String[]` or creates a single concatenated `String`.

To compare the same things you also should use the `getHeaders` method and then you will have the same result. Which means your request contains 2 header values for the given header.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. That helped us a lot.